# problems setting Linux Capabilities using Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, linux-capabilities

I want to set the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability for a certain subprocess in my python application. I tried a lot to do so, but I didn't succeed as no example is available, that makes it understandable for me.

What I did was that I installed python-prctl(1.6.1) and prctl(1.0.1) as suggested using pip and implemented `prctl.capbset.drop("setgid", prctl.CAP_NET_ADMIN)` into my application, right before creating the subprocess. However, it seems that even `capbset` can't be recognized.

In the subprocess I want to sniff the network using scapy.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to do is dropping the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` from capability bounding set, this is not the way to achieve what you have specified.

Instead, you should set the `inheritable` capabilities in the parent process and in the subprocess raise them to the `effective` set, to understand what each capability set does see [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891700/3147123) you have an example on how to use `python-prctl` (different scenario but should give you a generic overview).

You may also consider using ambient capabilities as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47982075/3147123).