# Run python-iptables (iptc) as non-root user

Tags: python, iptc, python-iptables

I am trying to run the python-iptables as a non-root user.

My script is test.py:

```
import iptc
import os

uid = os.getuid()
print("Real user ID of the current process:", uid)

table = iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER)
print("Table is:".format(table))
```

I tried:

1. Giving the capability CAP_NET_ADMIN to `/usr/bin/python2.7` (outcome is: `$ getcap /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7 = cap_net_admin+eip` ) and executing `/usr/bin/python2.7 ./test.py` as described in: [Python Scapy sniff without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215201/python-scapy-sniff-without-root/47982075#47982075)
2. Compiling and running with ambient capabilities as defined in: https://gist.github.com/tomix86/32394a43be70c337cbf1e0c0a56cbd8d and executing `./ambient -c '12' /usr/bin/python2.7 ./test.py`
3. I haven't yet tested with python-prctl but I soon plan to as described in: [Unable to get CAP_CHOWN and CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE working for regular user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883010/unable-to-get-cap-chown-and-cap-dac-override-working-for-regular-user/31891700#31891700)

The logs are:

```
('Real user ID of the current process:', 1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    table = iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/iptc/ip4tc.py", line 1566, in __new__
    obj._init(name, autocommit)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/iptc/ip4tc.py", line 1582, in _init
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/iptc/ip4tc.py", line 1619, in refresh
    self.strerror()))
iptc.ip4tc.IPTCError: can't initialize filter: Permission denied (you must be root)
```

My kernel is:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.224-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

My python version is:

```
Python 2.7.5
```

My python-iptables version is:

```
python-iptables            0.12.0
```

I can successfully run "iptables -L" as a non-root user but I cannot successfully run iptc python commands as a non-root user.

Is there any other way to give my python script capabilities or is it related to the iptc code?

Could it be failing because it requires additional capabilities?

Comment: It's related to the operating system. You're trying to change system-wide setting, so you need to be a super user to be able to do that.

Comment: This is why I try to add the capabilities it requires.

Answer (score 0):

run python with sudo or run this python under superuser credentials. Because iptables requires (sudo) superuser credentials.

for example:
`sudo python test.py`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

iptc is not shell'ing out to run iptables - it's loading the c-bindings directly. As the script is calling python underneath, you have to give python these capabilities directly.

Giving capabilities to python system-wide is not a good idea(tm). Making a local-copy of python runnable only by the user, with the additional capabilities of cap_raw/net will do the trick.

```
njl@mymachine:~/myproject $ which python3
/home/njl/bin/python3

njl@mymachine:~/myproject $ getcap ~/bin/python3
/home/njl/bin/python3 cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=ep

njl@mymachine:~/myproject $ ls -l ~/bin/python3
-rwx------ 1 njl njl 4703672 Jan  7 21:18 /home/njl/bin/python3
njl@mymachine:~/myproject $ ./demo.py
{'INPUT': [], 'FORWARD': [], 'OUTPUT': []}
```

Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import iptc

def dump_iptables():
    return iptc.easy.dump_table('filter',ipv6=False)

print(dump_iptables())
```