# Run Python Code to capture live network traffic accessing all users rights

Tags: python, scapy, network-traffic

I am working on a virtual Machine by Oracle in Linux and my Linux version is 20.04 LTS and python version is 3.8. I have a python code which is used to capture live network traffic and save in a pcap file. The issue I am facing is that I want to run this code without any root or administrative or without sudo command.

test.py:

```
import time
from scapy.all import *
import uuid

# IP address to capture packets for
ip_address = "0.0.0.0"

start_time = time.time()
end_time = start_time + 10  # Capture for 10 seconds

# Create an empty list to store the packets
packets = []

def packet_callback(packet):
    if IP in packet:
        packets.append(packet)

# Create a capture filter to capture only packets from the specified IP address 
capture_filter = "ip host " + ip_address

sniff(prn=packet_callback, timeout=end_time-start_time, filter= capture_filter)

# Write all the packets to a single pcap file
filename = "/path_to_capture/capture_" + str(uuid.uuid1()) + ".pcap"
wrpcap(filename, packets)
print(len(packets))
```

I run my code in terminal by writing the following cmd:

```
sudo python3 test.py
```

By running this command, my code executes and capture the network traffic and save in a pcap file. But I want to execute my code without sudo or root privileges by writing a simple cmd:

```
python3 test.py
```

Kindly provide me the solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: what error do you get when you run it without sudo?

Comment: sniff(prn=packet_callback, timeout=end_time-start_time, filter= capture_filter)
  File "/home/sqit/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1263, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: Sniffing in promiscuous mode requires elevated permissions. You might be able to setup a user group in the OS to allow sniffing but that is not a programming topic anymore.

Comment: So, is there any solution to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the 'setcap' command in linux.

I have a experience of only 'C' language.

See the below link. (I'm not sure about Python)

https://medium.com/@badbot/safe-packet-capture-python-without-sudo-b08c4c4e531

Comment: setcap command is used just in case of pcap library but I am using scapy library

Comment: setcap didn't run in case of scapy

Comment: Check this link. Good luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215201/python-scapy-sniff-without-root

Comment: Dear @nevertheless thank you for your cooperation. It really helps me out of this problem